# How to disable particular time slots in telerik kendo scheduler?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I have been working on Telerik Kendo Scheduler. Here is the link 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/interaction/drag_and_drop_grid_scheduler

Its the same example I am using now, But I modified this example as per my requirement. Now I have a requirement where I need to disable some particular time slots like 05:00pm to 07:00pm. So I want to make that particular time slot as gray or disabled and when user try to drag event during this particular time slot, we will restrict user. See the snapshot below.

Above the scheduler there is a grid of events, and we drag events to scheduler with machines. Now according to machine working hours , we have to disable time slots in which they do not work or not available.

[image]

Update me in comment section, If I am unable to make you understand my situation.I will provide necessary details if required.